# What does an "Ack" mean in Apache Storm/Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

Can someone tell me what an "Ack" means for Apache Storm/Hadoop?  Does it mean that you "ack" a tuple when it is considered complete and didn't fail?  Removing it from the queue similar to how an ESB removes messages after processing them?  Where did that weird word come from and does it stand for something?  I looked here but was still a bit confused:  https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Concepts.html

Comment: You should definitely read thorough the docs. The reliability mechanism can be found [here](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html#what-is-storms-reliability-api). no offence but this question seems primarily opinion based to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as "Ack" in Apache Storm context, it lets the originating Spout know that the tuple has been fully processed.

> If Storm detects that a tuple is fully processed, Storm will call the ack method on the originating Spout task with the message id that the Spout provided to Storm.

[Link](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html)

It's a way to guarantee that a specific tuple has made it all the way threw the topology.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  Still a strange word eh:)

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's sort for "acknowledge", which is basically what it's doing. Acknowledging that a tuple has finished processing.

Comment: Thank you Morgan, that sounds right and makes sense to me now.